# android: How can I create subfolder in a `mipmap` folder, that can be accessed in code and layouts

Tags: android, android-resources, project-structure

I have my image resources in the various `mipmap` folders (`mipmap-xhdpi`, `mipmap-xxhdpi`, etc.) My project has hundreds of images (and growing) and it is becoming cumbersome that they are all in a single level in each directory.

I want to create a subfolder, such as "sprites" that I can reference in code with something like

`R.mipmap.sprites.sprite_name`

**How can I create usable sub-folders in my mipmap folders?**

When I create a new directory inside of a mipmap folder (using `New -> Directory`), the directory and its contents are invisible to anywhere that I am specifying a resource, namely:

• In the design-view of my xml layout, when I am browsing for an image resource for a background or an image button, the sub folders are hidden.

• In code, when I am specifying an image resource (`R.`... the subfolders are ignored).

Is there a correct way to do this? There appear to be some other directory options, Under the `New -> Folder` category, I have:

• `Assets folder`, described as "create a source root for assets to be included in the apk," but I don't want a root, I want a subdirectory.

• `Res Folder`, "source root for android resource files" 1. I don't see how this is different than an asset and 2. again, I don't want a root.

There are also several other folder types listed, that I am not familiar with.

**If this cannot be accomplished, what is the correct way to include (and organize) hundreds (or thousands) of image resources in a project? Is the only way to do it really to have them all in a single directory?**

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported, all files inside the "res" folder subfolders must be at the top level.

Comment: @Egor than what is the "proper" way to include a large number of image resources in an application? It seems silly that the only way is to have hundreds (or thousands) of images in a single directory

Comment: I am using the `assets` folder to store hundreds of icons in my app. You can create a subfolder, for examle `assets/sprites`.

Comment: @ByteHamster the mipmaps are special because the app will display images of a different resolution depending on the device resolution. Can I still accomplish that with the assets folder?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible automatically. You could write a function that checks the current density and chooses the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I create usable sub-folders in my mipmap folders?

You can't. Resource directories of any time, `mipmap` or otherwise, cannot have subdirectories.

> what is the correct way to include (and organize) hundreds (or thousands) of image resources in a project? Is the only way to do it really to have them all in a single directory?

If you are going to go with resources, then yes, though I would put them in `drawable` directories. `mipmap` is mostly for launcher icons.

> the mipmaps are special because the app will display images of a different resolution depending on the device resolution

No. `mipmap` and `drawable` resources support resource resampling at runtime, but it is based on density, not resolution.

As ByteHamster notes, you can put whatever sort of directory structure you want in `assets/`, though you will need to put the appropriate values into `BitmapFactory.Options` to help with the resampling based on density.

Comment: I didn't know mipmap was meant for launcher icons! (facepalm) ill look into drawables and assets. Thanks

Comment: @chiliNUT: In your defense, the whole `mipmap` thing is an under-documented bucket of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must keep all the resources in a single folder because, as you may know, different folders are used to [target different device classes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

The right way to organise your resources in by prefix: as stated in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips), you should use prefixes to make the resources appear in a meaningful order.